# how to pass form data to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to pass the first name and cars names to the other page, and I tried everything but doesn't work for me
once the user clicks on submit it's supposed to redirect to success.html page and show a message with their name and the cars they chose to test

this is page#1

```css
        h1 {
               text-align: center;
               color: #4A4A67;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-style: 'Amatic SC';
               font-size: 55px; }
        h3 { 
               font-size: 28px;
        }
        body { background-image: url("car.jpg");
               text-align: center;
               border-style: inset;
               border-color: #8CA7B3; 
               font-family: 'Amatic SC';
               font-weight: bold;
               color: #6F6F9B;
               border-radius: 25px;}
        #fname:focus{
                border-color: green;
                background-color: lightgreen}
        #Pnum:focus{
                border-color: green;
                background-color: lightgreen}
        span {
                color:darkred;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic SC' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen">   

 
    
    <script>
        
    function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById("fname").style.borderColor = "red";
      error1.textContent = "*Name must not be empty!"
    return false;}
    document.getElementById("fname").style.borderColor = "";
    error1.textContent = ""
        
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["Pnum"].value;
  if ( y == "" || isNaN(y) || (y.toString()).length>10 ){
    document.getElementById("Pnum").style.borderColor = "red";
    error2.textContent ="*Phone number invalid."
    return false;}
    document.getElementById("Pnum").style.borderColor = "";
    error2.textContent = ""
        
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("Age");
  var formValid = false;
  var i = 0;
  while ( !formValid && i < radios.length) {
  if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
        i++; }
  if (!formValid){
      error3.textContent = "Must check at least one option!"
      return false;}
      error3.textContent = "" 
        
  var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("cars");
  var formValid = false;
  var i = 0, x = 0;
  while ( i < checkbox.length ) {
  if (checkbox[i].checked) { x++; formValid = true; }
  i++; }
  if (!formValid) error4.textContent = "must check at least 1 option!" 
  if ( x > 3 ) { error4.textContent = "must check at most 3!"
                   return false; }
          // Getting the value of your text input
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;

            // Storing the value above into localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("fname", fname);

        return formValid;
        
                }  
     
        
    </script>
    
    
</head>
    
<body>

   
<h1>Car Test Request</h1>
<h3>please fill in the form to make your car test request.</h3>
    
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="file:///C:/Users/s/Desktop/457/assignment%202/success.html" method="GET"> 
    
  <label for="FirstName">please enter your name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=""><span id="error1"></span><br><br>
    
  <label for="PhoneNumber">please enter your phone number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="Pnum" name="Pnum" value=""><span id="error2"></span><br><br>
    
  How old are you? <span id="error3"></span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="Age" id="18-23">18-23<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Age" id="23-30">23-30<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Age" id="31-39">31-39<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Age" id="40+">40+<br><br>
    
  <h>choose the wanted car(s) for the test drive:</h> <span id="error4"></span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Bentley">
  <label for="cars">Bentley</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="BMW">
  <label for="cars">BMW</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Cadillac">
  <label for="cars">Cadillac</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Dodge">
  <label for="cars">Dodge</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Fiat">
  <label for="cars">Fiat</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Ford">
  <label for="cars">Ford</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Jaguar">
  <label for="cars">Jaguar</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cars" name="cars" value="Mazda">
  <label for="cars">Mazda</label><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>


      <input type="submit">
      <input type="reset">
   <br><br>

</form>

    
 </body> </html>
```

this is page#2 (success.html)

```css
        h1 {
               text-align: center;
               color: #4A4A67;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-style: 'Amatic SC';
               font-size: 55px; }
        h3 { 
               font-size: 28px;
        }
        body { background-image: url("car.jpg");
               text-align: center;
               border-style: inset;
               border-color: #8CA7B3; 
               font-family: 'Amatic SC';
               font-weight: bold;
               color: #6F6F9B;
               border-radius: 25px;}
        #fname:focus{
                border-color: green;
                background-color: lightgreen}
        #Pnum:focus{
                border-color: green;
                background-color: lightgreen}
        span {
                color:darkred;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen">   

        <script>
          //  var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;       
          function init() {
        // Retrieving the text input's value which was stored into localStorage
        var fname = localStorage.getItem("fname");

    
    }
        
        </script>
        
    
    
    </head>
<body>
    
    
    <p>
    <span id='fname'></span>, thanks for your request! <br> 
    we will call you soon to schedule a test drive for: <br>
    </p>
    <img src="bye.gif" alt="bye bye" width="200" height="200">
    
    
    
    
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Did you try reading the query parameter in the success.html?  The selected form-values would be passed in queryparams, as you have set form method to `get`.

Comment: can you show me how to do that, please?

Comment: You really should lesson the footprint of your question to relevant code only...

Comment: Use `params = new URLSearchParams(location.search) ` and iterate through the params.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Examples .  Also check this post   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript.

Comment: One more thing, even if not related, the font just does not fit the theme at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using method="GET" try using method="POST" and the proper URL inside the action=" second page URL " so that the data that you submit will be posted to the second page.Now use the localStorage.getItem() method on second page to get the data and show the data by using DOM like document.getElementId("").innerHTML = fname;